# Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DUMMY / Invalid schema SYS

Tags: hana, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-business-technology-platform

(Re-posting form SAP Blog)
Was trying to integrate an HANA schema and HDI container service in cloud foundry trial version with a JAVA application on cloud foundry, and encountered an error as below:

> Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DUMMY
>
> [image]

Could anyone help me in understanding, what wrong here? Am I supposed to assign an authorization?

I am just running on Cloud Foundry trial version.

This is our simple connection test program:

```
@Override 
protected void doGet( final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response ) 
    throws IOException 
{
    logger.info("I am running!"); 
    Context ctx = null; 
    Connection con = null; 
    Statement stmt = null; 
    ResultSet rs = null; 
    try { 
      ctx = new InitialContext(); 
      DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB"); 
      con = ds.getConnection( ); 
      stmt = con.createStatement(); 
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("select current_user as myuser from DUMMY"); 
      rs.next(); 
      response.getWriter().append("Served at:").append(rs.getString(1)).append(request.getContextPath());
    }catch(NamingException e){
           e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (SQLException e) { 
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image]

and I even created a `context.xml` under `META-INF` under `webapp`.

Am I missing anything over here? Could someone help me in understanding the limitation of HANA on a trial version of Cloud Foundry?

Tried giving `SYS.DUMMY`, but still throws an error:

> Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid schema name: SYS
>
> [image]

Thanks, Regards, Girish

Answer (score 2):

You can define a synonym for DUMMY in the `.hdbsynonym` file which can be used on behalf of an actual SYS.DUMMY

```
{ 
  "my_namespace.my_db::DUMMY" : { 
     "target" : { 
              "schema" : "SYS", 
              "object" : "DUMMY" 
     }
  }
}
```

and use it in your procedures or SQL queries like so:

```
SELECT SESSION_CONTEXT('XS_EMAIL') AS "EMAIL" FROM "my_namespace.my_db::DUMMY";
```

*Note: If you are using earlier version of HANA 2 (< SP3) you would need an additional `.hdbgrants` file.*